# Ambiguity in “Didn’t do it on purpose”

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I was thinking, couldn’t “I didn’t do it on purpose” take on two meanings or be interpreted two ways?

1. The act was unintentional, I did not mean for it to happen.
2. I specifically chose not to do it, it was a conscious decision.

I feel like number two isn’t as idiomatic as number one, is that right? But otherwise how do you determine which meaning is intended?

Comment: It is pretty much a set phrase, and always takes the first meaning.

Comment: There are [plenty of phrases](https://www.alphadictionary.com/fun/headlines.html) in English that can be interpreted in two ways. How do you know which is intended? **Context**.

Comment: *In theory* the cited text could be seen as ambiguous, but in practice any halfway-competent native speaker would say *I **deliberately** didn't do it* or similar (since the "natural" position for the adverb would be *I didn't do it **deliberately***, the reader/listener would know to assume the non-standard meaning when presented with a non-standard sequence). Note that ***on purpose*** doesn't really work for this "transposition", but I don't know exactly why that's so.